# how to store date and time in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have one field displaying date and time in following format:

```
30/01/2011, 4:57 pm
```

I want to store this in mysql using data type datetime.

After getting value from post, I try to store it in database but its storing `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in table.

How can I store above specified values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `date` and `strtotime` like this:

```
$date = '30/01/2011, 4:57 pm';
$to_mysql_date = date('Y-m-d h:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $date)));
echo $to_mysql_date;
```

**Result:**

```
2011-01-30 04:57:00
```

### [Working Example](http://codepad.org/PJVb6OsW)

Now you can use the `$to_mysql_date` variable to insert the date in MySQL-friendly format :)

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Comment: but its giving output 1970-01-01 04:00:00

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, [that gave me the wrong date](http://codepad.org/CSCmp8OS)...

Comment: @air: `date('d/m/Y, h:i a', strtotime($date));`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the formatting of your date you can always go for a VARCHAR field, but you're going to miss the purpose of datetime. Or you can transform that to a timestamp and use the TIMESTAMP field.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use:

```
$sd = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/M/Y, H:i a', '30/01/2011, 4:57 pm');
$mysqldate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($sd->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')));
```